# How to break sales query results by day

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

I have a sales query by date range, where the date range is defined by user input. I would like to divide the results by day. i.e.: say the user input the date range from 01/01/16 - 01/15/16, I would like the break the results for each day. 
I'm using DATENAME(DD,T1.[DocDate]) to break it, and it is kind of working, but the results are no accurate. I figure I have to use the same break in the Returns subquery. Please see the full query below:

Thank you

```
SELECT
'2016' as 'Year',
t4.remarks as 'Department',
DATENAME(DD,T1.[DocDate]) as 'Day',
sum(t0.[quantity])-(ISNULL(p.quantity,0)) as 'Quantity',
sum(t0.linetotal - t0.linetotal*t1.discprcnt/100)-(ISNULL(p.total,0)) as 'Total',
sum(T0.[GrssProfit])-(ISNULL(p.profit,0)) as 'Profit $',
(sum(T0.[GrssProfit])-(ISNULL(p.profit,0)))/(sum(t0.linetotal - t0.linetotal*t1.discprcnt/100)-(ISNULL(p.total,0)))*100 as 'Profit%'

FROM INV1 T0 with (nolock)
INNER JOIN OINV T1 with (nolock) on t0.docentry = t1.docnum
INNER JOIN OSLP T2 with (nolock) on t0.SlpCode = t2.SlpCode 
LEFT JOIN OHEM T3 with (nolock) on t0.slpcode = t3.SalesPrson 
LEFT JOIN OUDP T4 with (nolock)  on t3.dept = t4.Code

--BEGINS QUERY FOR THE RETURNS-- 
left join (select t9.name as 'dept',sum(t5.quantity) as 'quantity',sum(t5.linetotal - t5.linetotal*t6.discprcnt/100) as 'total',sum(t5.grssprofit) as 'profit'
from [dbo].[rin1] t5 with (nolock)
inner join orin t6 with (nolock) on t5.docentry = t6.docentry
INNER JOIN OSLP T7 with (nolock) on t5.SlpCode = t7.SlpCode 
LEFT JOIN OHEM T8 with (nolock) on t5.slpcode = t8.SalesPrson 
LEFT JOIN OUDP T9 with (nolock) on t8.dept = t9.Code
INNER JOIN OITM T10 with (nolock) on t5.itemcode = t10.itemcode
where t5.docdate between '[%1]' and '[%2]' and t10.invntitem = 'Y'
and (t5.linetotal - (t5.linetotal*t6.discprcnt/100)) <> '0'
group by t9.name) p on p.dept = t4.name
--ENDS QUERY FOR THE RETURNS-- 

WHERE t1.docdate between '[%1]' and '[%2]'
and t4.remarks is not null
and t4.remarks = 'perfume provider'
and (t0.linetotal - (t0.linetotal*t1.discprcnt/100)) <> '0'

group by DATENAME(DD,T1.[DocDate]),t4.remarks,p.quantity,p.total,p.profit
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your current query and desired results, and for those of us that don't have Sap B1 installed, also share the relevant table's DDL and some sample data as DML.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks. I just edited and added the full query and some more details

Comment: @CesarAugusto  It would also be nice if you could clean your code up a bit so it is readable...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a sub-query for your returns (with the same kind of group by as your Invoices query), you should use a UNION instead. Your Group-By is fine, but like you mentioned, your subquery is going to result in bad data.

Any time you have distinct "starting points" for your data, a Union is the way to go.

Comment: But when I use UNION, I get to separate lines of results, for the sales and the returns. I use the subquery so I can subtract the returns from the sales and get the final number

Comment: So wrap a select around the UNION and group your data there.

Comment: but how do I do that?